# Unable to install git repo by pip

Tags: python-3.x, pip, anaconda

I am trying to install a git repo's master branch source by pip and I am using the command

```
pip install git+https://github.com/apache/systemml/@master#egg=systemml&subdirectory=src/main/python
```

But I encountered the error:

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
>   C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3hqjwj06\systemml\
>   'subdirectory' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

So I researched about it and found the [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991403/pip-install-unroll-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-code-1)
 question  and followed the following steps of the most upvoted answer but it didn't work in my case. I also tried installing python 3.6 and it also did not help.

I am using Windows OS and 3.7 python

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Since you are using master, can you also post your errors with this command `pip install git+https://github.com/apache/systemml.git`

Comment: Same error occuring

Comment: Is `Apache Spark 2.x`  installed Also is `SPARK_HOME` set to installed location?

Comment: Yes it is, but ain't it more of a python pip installation error rather than Spark error

Comment: Yes, I know that, the reason I am asking this is because I am unable to replicate this error, so I am unable to give a direct answer, thus I am trying to investigate something that might differ in our system, Can you log the Install using `pip -v --log /tmp/pip.log install git+<repo location>` aslo what happens if you try to install it without the git repo.

Comment: I am getting an error `pip._internal.exceptions.InstallationError: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\TEST~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-c8dlufu4\systemml\` where I found my username is test and in this it showing TEST~1

Comment: Sorry Unable to replicate this, maybe someone who can will be able to help.

Comment: What OS and shell do you use? Depending on a configuration you might have to quote the URL, for example `pip install "git+https://github.com/apache/systemml/@master#egg=systemml&subdirectory=src/main/python"`

Comment: @user10958683 Oh gosh thanks a lot the quote did the trick .I feel embarrased to ask this question